# How to mimic this pseudo code? and conflicting packages

Tags: algorithms, pseudocode

I am trying to mimic this algorithm but the layout is not working. How can I get the same layout (or something close to it)? See code below picture.

I am using the package algo and the algo.sty link from where it can be downloaded I also added in the code.
If you know how i can make something close to this that is without this package or other package that is more than welcome!

In combination with the package `\usepackage{algorithm}` it does not work.

**THis is what i want**
[image: Desired output]

**This one is mine is incorrect**
[image: Wrong]

```
\documentstyle{article} 
%\usepackage{algorithm}% when I add this package it is not working, but i need this package for other code


\usepackage[named]{algo}
        %You can download algo.sty from:
        %https://www.win.tue.nl/~kbuchin/teaching/algo.sty
        \begin{document}
        \begin{algorithm}{SMOTE}[$T$,~$N$,~$k$] {       
            \qinput{Number of minority class samples $T$; Amount of SMOTE $N$\%; Number of nearest neighbors $k$}
            \qoutput{($N/100$) * $T$ synthetic minority class samples}} 
            \qcom{{\it{If $N$ is less than 100\%, randomize the minority class samples as only a random percent
    of them will be SMOTEd.}}} \\
        \qif $N < 100$ \\
        \qthen Randomize the $T$ minority class samples \\
        $T = (N/100) * T$ \\
        $N = 100$ 
        \qfi \\
        {\bf{endif}} \\
        $ N = (int)(N/100) $ \qcom{{\it{The amount of SMOTE is assumed to be in integral multiples of 100.}}} \\
        $k$ = Number of nearest neighbors \\
        $numattrs$ = Number of attributes \\
        $Sample[~][~]$: array for original minority class samples \\
        $newindex$: keeps a count of number of synthetic samples generated, initialized to 0 \\
        $Synthetic[~][~]$: array for synthetic samples \newline
    \qcom{{\it{Compute $k$ nearest neighbors for each minority class sample only.}}}\\
        \qfor $i \qlet 1$ \qto $T$ \\
            Compute $k$ nearest neighbors for $i$, and save the indices in the $nnarray$ \\
            Populate($N$, $i$, $nnarray$) \qrof  \\
        {\bf{endfor}} \newline 

        \qproc[N,~i,~nnarray]{Populate} \qcom{{\it{Function to generate the synthetic samples.}}} \\ 
        \qwhile $N \neq 0$ \\
            Choose a random number between $1$ and $k$, call it $nn$. This step chooses one of the $k$ nearest 
            neighbors of $i$.  \\
        \qfor $attr \qlet 1$ \qto $numattrs$ \\
            Compute: $dif = Sample[nnarray[nn]][attr] - Sample[i][attr]$  \\
            Compute: $gap$ = random number between 0 and 1 \\
            $Synthetic[newindex][attr] = Sample[i][attr] + gap * dif$ \qrof \\  
        {\bf{endfor}} \\
            $newindex$++ \\
        $N = N - 1$ \qelihw \\
        {\bf{endwhile}} \\
        \qreturn  \qcom{{\it{End of Populate.}}}\newline
        End of Pseudo-Code.
    \end{algorithm}
    \end{document}
```

**Edit:**
Thanks to Leandris to mimic it I only had to remove the blank line as suggested.

Comment: What  all these `\qinput,\qoutput,\qif,&c.` commands beginning with `q`?

Comment: @Bernard should it be without q?

Comment: I've always seen them without q. Where did you take it from?

Comment: What isn't working?  It's much easier to help you if you identify what exactly isn't coming out the way you'd like.  It's a pretty big chunk of code for us to scrutinize to find the differences between it and your picture.  You also say you're trying to "mimic" it, and we don't know what the parameters of "mimicking" it are.  Do you want a full, perfect duplication?  Or is there a "close enough"?

Comment: @dgoodmaniii Something similar is fine, the most important part is the that the indentation part is correct, I added a picture of the wrong version

Comment: Pleas make your example code compilable. Currently, there is a tleast one package missing that allows for the use of the `algorithm` environment. Since there are sevelar algorithm / pseudocode related packages, please clarif which of them you use.

Comment: @leandriis added

Comment: @jenniferruurs: `\documentstyle` should most likely be `\documentclass` instead. Please also add, where you got the `algo` package from. The only algorithm related packages I could find on CTAN are the following: https://ctan.org/topic/pseudocode

Comment: @leandriis I just added where i got algo.sty from (just 1 second ago)

Comment: @leandriis but if you know another solution that is more than welcome

Comment: @Bernard I added the package from where i got the commands!

Comment: @jenniferruurs: If I use your MWE and replace `\documentstyle` with `\documentclass`, I get a bunch of error messages like `Paragraph ended before \a@genalgo was complete.`. Do you alos get these? If so, please do not look at the pdf that you get. Even if you get something that on first glance resembles a pdf file, there can still be issues with it. After an error, TeX only tries to recover enough to syntax check more of the file, it does not try to make sensible output after an error.

Comment: @jenniferruurs: To get rid of the aboe mentioned error message(s), simply remove the blank line befre the first `\qinput` command. You should then get the desired output (apart from an overfull box warning).

Comment: @leandriis this indeed solved my question (I feel stupid) thank you!

Comment: @leandriis I also need to use the package `\usepackage{algorithm}` for other code, when I do that i again looks not the same, what is going wrong?